# Do I need to run "add" and "commit" before I "push" changes to upstream (making a PR)?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, upstream-branch

At the bottom there are contribution rules of a project in GitHub. Particularly step `4` is under the question. It doesn't say anything if I need to run `add` and `commit` commands before I run `git push --set-upstream`.

Because when I have made my changes, I get modified and untracked files in my local repo. So do I need to `add` and `commit` them before `git push --set-upstream`?

[image]

> 1. Fork the Material-UI repository on Github
> 2. Clone your fork to your local machine `git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:<yourname>/material-ui.git`
>      (For the `next` branch, add the `-b next` flag to the above command.)
> 3. Create a branch `git checkout -b my-topic-branch`
> 4. **Make your changes, lint, then push to github with `git push --set-upstream origin my-topic-branch`.**
> 5. Visit github and make your pull request.

Comment: You *always* need to `add` and `commit` before `push`ing. That's how the `git` workflow, well, works. :)

Comment: @Bytewave, yes, I'm well aware, but why is it ignored in step `4`? I'm making my first PR, I don't know the process, and when I read *make changes, then **push** them right away* without mentioning `add` and `commit`, it makes me confused.
Thanks )

Comment: Because the maintainers of that project did not think that it would be necessary to include a git tutorial in their contribution guide.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to add and commit your changes (in a new pr branch you just created), don't forget also to check your user.name/user.email.
Check the output of:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Those have nothing to do with your GitHub account but will be the visible information attached to the commit you will push. Make sure they are right *before* your commit.

See "[Setting your username in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need add and commit your changes before pushing your code to your github repository.